# difference between df.loc[:, columns] and df.loc[:][columns]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to normalize some columns of a pandas data frame using `MinMaxScaler` in this way:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
numericals = ["TX_TIME_SECONDS",'TX_Amount']
```

while I do in this way:

```
df.loc[:][numericals] = scaler.fit_transform(df.loc[:][numericals])
```

it's not done inplace and `df` is not changed;

whereas, when I do in this way:

```
df.loc[:, numericals] = scaler.fit_transform(df.loc[:][numericals])
```

the numerical columns of `df` are changed in place,

**So,** What's the difference between `df.loc[:, ~]` and `df.loc[:][~]`

Answer (score 1):

`df.loc[:][numericals]` selects all rows and then selects columns "TX_TIME_SECONDS" and 'TX_Amount' of the **returning object**, and assigns some value to it. The problem is, the returning object might be a copy so this may not change the actual DataFrame.

The correct way of making this assignment is using `df.loc[:, numericals]`, because with `.loc` you are guaranteed to modify the original DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read some documentation because this is pretty basic.

> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html
>
> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-loc/